# Implementing an indexer for a struct in c++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have the following triangle struct in c++/qt and I want to implement an indexer for it so that I can access any of the vertices by index, can anyone help me with the problem?

Here's the struct:

```
struct Triangle
{
    QVector3D *a;
    QVector3D *b;
    QVector3D *c;
}
```

Comment: Give an example of how you want and what it should return?

Comment: I want the indexer to act like the array indexers; for instance instead of "Triangle.a" I want to use triangle[0] just like c# indexers!

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector<QVector3D *>` instead?

Comment: Off topic but... is there a good reason for members `a`, `b` and `c` being of type `QVector3D *` rather than simply `QVector3D`?

Answer (score 2):

If you really need it, you could add operator [] to your class like that:

```
struct Triangle
{
QVector3D *a;
QVector3D *b;
QVector3D *c;
QVector3D * operator[](int n) {return n==0?a:n==1?b:n==2?c:Q_NULLPTR;}
};

Triangle tr; 
//.....
auto test = tr[0]; //will return vector 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `std::array`

```
struct Triangle {
    std::array<QVector3D *, 3> points;
    QVector3D * operator[](int n) {return points[i];}
};

Triangle tr; 
auto test = tr[0];        //will return first component (former 'a')\
```

Since points is public in the `struct Triangle` you don't need the operator overload.

```
auto test = tr.points[0]; //will return first component (former 'a')
```

If you don't intend to add more functionality into the `struct Triangle`, consider to use

```
using Triangle = std::array<QVector3D *, 3>;
```

Comment: you can even use simple array or QList or QVector directly, but I thought author need a,b,c somewhere else, because the whole struct is actually overhead

Comment: @Xplatforms `using Triangle = std::vector<QVector3D *>;` will do the job.

Comment: Assuming a triangle always has 3 points, `std::array<QVector3D *, 3>` is a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are used to C#, where to create objects you need `new`. In C++, you don't.

```
struct Triangle
{
    QVector3D a;
    QVector3D b;
    QVector3D c;
    QVector3D& operator[](int);
}

QVector3D& Triangle::operator[](int which)
{
     switch(which)
     {
          case 0: return a;
          case 1: return b;
          case 2: return c;
          default: throw std::out_of_range("Must be 0-2");
     }
}
```

This declares both "get" and "set" in the C# sense, you can use it on either side of assignment, with the ordinary meaning. E.g.

```
Triangle t;
auto point = t[1];
t[2] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```